# How to stop creating a new 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' hash every time I publish?

Tags: asp.net, azure, hash, version, publish

We have a big project and compiling the views takes a significant amount of time. Every time I publish a new version to Azure and try to run it locally again afterwards, it seems to be using a fresh 'hash' for the Temporary ASP.NET files directory.

This triggers a recompile of every partial view that is in the project (a lot) and this takes a few minutes for the first load.

What is deciding this hash? Can I prevent from a new hash being generated every time I publish so I don't have to rebuild the cache every time?

```
[...]
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-2-131419173936667684): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8385e8d5\186cbd8c\App_Web__testenvironmentmark.cshtml.639c3968.3fnosuwi.dll'. 
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-2-131419173936667684): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8385e8d5\186cbd8c\App_Web__jsexceptionlogger.cshtml.639c3968.r2uq3sws.dll'. 
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-2-131419173936667684): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8385e8d5\186cbd8c\App_Web__shared.cshtml.639c3968.gxet4pmp.dll'. 
[...]
```

I'm refferring to the **8385e8d5\186cbd8c** part.

Comment: By locally, do you mean Visual Studio/localhost? If you're running from VS you can disable;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-code-analysis-for-managed-code

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a compile of your views: e.g. http://gunnarpeipman.com/2016/08/asp-net-mvc-precompiling-views/

This also improves the cold startup time for your website.